# How to apply a function on multiple files from same sample and combine them?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr, rbind

I have many Sample files in a directory `Data`. There are around 80 samples. Each sample has 3 output files with different formats having sample name as a prefix. The setup looks like below. I'm showing only a few sample files here.

```
Data
 |___ PFRT001_disions.tsv
 |___ PFRT001_predictions.tsv
 |___ PFRT001_tool.beans.results.gz
 |___ PFRT007_disions.tsv
 |___ PFRT007_predictions.tsv
 |___ PFRT007_tool.beans.results.gz
 |___ PFRT009_disions.tsv
 |___ PFRT009_predictions.tsv
 |___ PFRT009_tool.beans.results.gz
 |___ PFRT023_disions.tsv
 |___ PFRT023_predictions.tsv
 |___ PFRT023_tool.beans.results.gz
 |___ PFRT098_disions.tsv
 |___ PFRT098_predictions.tsv
 |___ PFRT098_tool.beans.results.gz
```

Now, I'm applying a function on each sample (3 files with different formats) and saving the output of the function with a name.

Here I'm showing how I applied the function on a sample `PFRT001`

```
sample1 <- single_sample(disionsfile = file.path("/path/to/directory","Data","PFRT001_disions.tsv"),
  predictionsfile = file.path("/path/to/directory","Data","PFRT001_predictions.tsv"),
  expFile = file.path("/path/to/directory","Data","PFRT001_tool.beans.results.gz"),
  tumorID = "PFRT001",
  Filter = FALSE)
```

Then again I ran the same function on a sample `PFRT007`

```
sample2 <- single_sample(disionsfile = file.path("/path/to/directory","Data","PFRT007_disions.tsv"),
      predictionsfile = file.path("/path/to/directory","Data","PFRT007_predictions.tsv"),
      expFile = file.path("/path/to/directory","Data","PFRT007_tool.beans.results.gz"),
      tumorID = "PFRT007",
      Filter = FALSE)
```

I'm applying this function individually on each sample (3 files) and saving that into a name and then combining them like below:

```
All <- do.call("rbind", list(sample1, sample2))
```

I have 80 samples, where each sample has 3 files like above. How to apply the above function on multiple sample files and save the output of each sample with different names? And `rbind` all the outputs? I want to do it in `R`. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your function `single_sample` returns a `data.frame`, `map_dfr` is the perfect function for you:

```
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

file_names <- list.files(path = "/path/to/directory/Data")
unique_names <- unique(str_extract(file_names, ".+?(?=_)"))

all_data <- unique_names %>% 
  map_dfr(~single_sample(
    disionsfile = file.path("/path/to/directory","Data",paste0(.x, "_disions.tsv")),
    predictionsfile = file.path("/path/to/directory","Data", paste0(.x, "P_predictions.tsv")),
    expFile = file.path("/path/to/directory","Data",paste0(.x, "_tool.beans.results.gz")),
    tumorID = .x,
    Filter = FALSE
  ), .id = "sample")
```

`.id = "sample"` adds a column named `sample` that contains the information from which `.x` the data comes from

Comment: Thanks a ton. This is very useful. I accepted the answer but couldn't upvote. Once I get 15 reputations I will upvote. BTW, there is a `,` missing at the end of `predictionsfile`.